# CrashLoopBackOff error while deploying postgresql to gke

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy PostgreSQL to GKE and here is my PersistentVolumeClaim definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-pvc
  namespace: db
  labels:
    app: imgress-db
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 400Mi
```

and this is deployment/service definition:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: imgress-db
  namespace: db
spec:
  serviceName: imgress-db
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: imgress-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: imgress-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: imgress-db
          image: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: DATABASE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: POSTGRES_DB
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: POSTGRES_USER
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: imgress-db
  namespace: db
spec:
  selector:
    app: imgress-db
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      port: 5432
```

First I run:

```
kubectl apply -f postgres-pvc.yaml
```

and then:

```
kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yaml
```

but I get this notorious error when I run `kubectl get pods -A`:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
db          imgress-db-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (2m15s ago)   8m26s
```

For `kubectl describe pvc postgres-pvc -n db` I get this result:

```
Name:          postgres-pvc
Namespace:     db
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-c6369764-1106-4a7d-887c-0e4009968115
Labels:        app=imgress-db
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      1Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       imgress-db-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                                                                                              Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                                                                                              -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   31m   persistentvolume-controller                                                                       waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           31m   pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-e0f710dc594c4eb5ac14-5c62-e039-vm_ca2409ad-83a8-4139-93b4-4fffbacbf44f  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "db/postgres-pvc"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  31m   pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-e0f710dc594c4eb5ac14-5c62-e039-vm_ca2409ad-83a8-4139-93b4-4fffbacbf44f  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-c6369764-1106-4a7d-887c-0e4009968115
```

and for `kubectl describe pod imgress-db-0 -n db` I get this result (please pay attention to `Back-off restarting failed container` on the last line):

```
Name:             imgress-db-0
Namespace:        db
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             gke-imgress-default-pool-e9bdef38-hjhv/10.156.0.5
Start Time:       Fri, 24 Feb 2023 13:44:15 +0500
Labels:           app=imgress-db
                  controller-revision-hash=imgress-db-7f557d4b88
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=imgress-db-0
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.84.2.49
IPs:
  IP:           10.84.2.49
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/imgress-db
Containers:
  imgress-db:
    Container ID:   containerd://96140ec0b0e369ca97822361a770abcb82e27b7924bc90e17111ab354e51d6aa
    Image:          postgres
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/postgres@sha256:901df890146ec46a5cab7a33f4ac84e81bac2fe92b2c9a14fd649502c4adf954
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Fri, 24 Feb 2023 13:50:09 +0500
      Finished:     Fri, 24 Feb 2023 13:50:11 +0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  6
    Environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST:      <set to the key 'DATABASE_HOST' of config map 'db-configmap'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_DB:        <set to the key 'POSTGRES_DB' of config map 'db-configmap'>    Optional: false
      POSTGRES_USER:      <set to the key 'POSTGRES_USER' of config map 'db-configmap'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD' in secret 'db-secret'>     Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/postgresql/data from postgres-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-tfsf9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  postgres-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  postgres-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-tfsf9:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                   ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled               6m51s                  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned db/imgress-db-0 to gke-imgress-default-pool-e9bdef38-hjhv
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  6m46s                  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-c6369764-1106-4a7d-887c-0e4009968115"
  Normal   Pulled                  6m42s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "postgres" in 365.355391ms
  Normal   Pulled                  6m39s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "postgres" in 236.532115ms
  Normal   Pulled                  6m26s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "postgres" in 278.12995ms
  Normal   Created                 5m59s (x4 over 6m42s)  kubelet                  Created container imgress-db
  Normal   Started                 5m59s (x4 over 6m41s)  kubelet                  Started container imgress-db
  Normal   Pulled                  5m59s                  kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "postgres" in 348.694043ms
  Normal   Pulling                 5m10s (x5 over 6m42s)  kubelet                  Pulling image "postgres"
  Normal   Pulled                  5m9s                   kubelet                  Successfully pulled image "postgres" in 288.848351ms
  Warning  BackOff                 95s (x25 over 6m38s)   kubelet                  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Result of `kubectl logs imgress-db-0 -n db`:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
initdb: detail: It contains a lost+found directory, perhaps due to it being a mount point.
initdb: hint: Using a mount point directly as the data directory is not recommended.
Create a subdirectory under the mount point.
```

I've already seen some related questions asked on SO but I guess it can be caused by different problems.

**What I tried**:

1. adding user and password as an env variables
2. deleting everything in the namespace and recreating
3. deleting livenessprobe and readinessprobe from the description

Comment: Can you try `describe`ing your `deployment` as well? Is there any noteworthy output from `kubectl logs imgress-db-0 -n db`?

Comment: @dan1st edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding two things to description:

1. `PGDATA` env variable inside containers:

   ```
     env:
       - name: PGDATA
         value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
   ```
2. `subPath: postgres` under `volumeMounts`

Now my deployment file looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: imgress-db
  namespace: db
spec:
  serviceName: imgress-db
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: imgress-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: imgress-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: imgress-db
          image: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: DATABASE_HOST
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: POSTGRES_DB
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-configmap
                  key: POSTGRES_USER
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            - name: PGDATA
              value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: imgress-db
  namespace: db
spec:
  selector:
    app: imgress-db
  ports:
    - name: postgres
      port: 5432
```